# LAMP stack's PHP not working (Ubuntu 13.10 / Apache 2.4.6)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

Having problems with PHP on my LAMP stack: PHP scripts aren't being parsed at all. I setup Ubuntu 13.10 on clear machine... And I see now there only clear HTML from page but PHP tags are just like text

Actually, what I have:

***$ /usr/sbin/apache2ctl status | grep Version***

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1
```

***$ tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/error.log***

```
[Sat Dec 14 19:33:16.307184 2013] [core:notice] [pid 15457] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

***$ apache2ctl -S***

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server videosurgeon.ll (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vs.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost videosurgeon.ll (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vs.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost videosurgeon.ll (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vs.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

***$ apache2ctl -M | grep php***

```
 php5_module (shared)
```

***$ cat /work/VS/httpdocs/test.php***

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

***$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vs.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName videosurgeon.ll

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

    DocumentRoot /work/VS/httpdocs/

    <Directory /work/VS/httpdocs/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,alert, emerg.
    LogLevel notice

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</virtualHost>
```

***$ /usr/bin/php --version***

```
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:22:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

---

**UPD.1:** it's mine apache2.conf : http://ge.tt/6Yd8Jj91/v/0

---

**UPD.2:** Today I умут tried to remove everything and just re-install LAMP. The result is exactly the same: **PHP does not works.**

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

But also interesting that phpmyadmin works fine. I just install it as:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cgi phpmyadmin
```

It turns out that there (in phpmyadmin) are some settings that give it to use PHP...

Comment: Are you hure modphp is installed.  You could conceivably have installed a non-apache version of php: try `apt-get install -y apache2-mod-php5 ; service apache2 restart`

Comment: If the above suggestion fails, you can also try the 'LAMP server' option in tasksel ($ sudo tasksel).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. building a development environment on debian. did you find a solution to this problem in the end?

Answer (score 11):

Just had the same problem. You have to use `<?PHP` instead of `<?` or change the following config:

**/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

```
; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
; of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily
; confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because
; this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
; supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have these lines in your httpd.conf:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Also make sure your php module is loaded:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

After that, restart apache and clear your browser's cache before retrying.

Comment: there is no httpd.conf at all

Comment: there is apache2.conf

Comment: Apache does not use httpd.conf in Debian-based installs. They have a site-based configuration located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled that allows you to use a2ensite and a2dissite to enable/disable configuration files for certain virtual hosts. They also have a central configuration file called apache2.conf. Either try putting what Sebas has listed in apache2.conf or in the relevant site configuration file in sites-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason default virtual host is not executing php by default:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/407744/apache-doesnt-execute-php-files-but-makes-me-download-them

Enable php engine explicitly:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```